VSCode autocomplete / hints not working for PySCIPopt (installed in conda env)
The problem:
VSCode is not showing me hints or autocomplete options for methods of objects from the pyscipopt library.
Minimal working example:
To test that pysciopt is correctly installed, I wrote and ran following code:
from pyscipopt import Model
m = Model("test")
m.addVar()
m.printStatistics()

VSCode let me autocomplete "pyscipopt" and "Model" on the first line, as well as "Model" on the second line.  However, it gave me no hints on 3rd and 4th line.
I ran the file via the "run python file" icon in upper right of the VSCode window, and it produced following output in the terminal:
SCIP Status        : problem creation / modification
Total Time         :       0.00
  reading          :       0.00
Original Problem   :
  Problem name     : test
  Variables        : 1 (0 binary, 0 integer, 0 implicit integer, 1 continuous)
  Constraints      : 0 initial, 0 maximal
  Objective        : minimize, 0 non-zeros (abs.min = 1e+20, abs.max = -1e+20)

Therefore, pyscipopt seems to be correctly installed and accessible to my python interpreter.
Extra details
I'm on windows 10.
I began by installing the miniforge anaconda env. manager.  Then I created a new environment named SCIPopt, activated it, and then I installed the library by typing
conda install --channel conda-forge pyscipopt
I restarted VSCode and set "Python 3.12.2 ('SCIPopt') ~\miniforge-pypy3\envs\SCIPopt\python.exe" as my python interpreter.  Before I had done that, running the minimal working example resulted in an error (no module named pyscipopt).
I also tried adding a settings.json file to my workspace with following contents:
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\{my user name}\\miniforge-pypy3\\envs\\SCIPopt"
}

but that did not help.
When I mouse over the 'addVar()' method in the example, VSCode shows me the following hint: "(function) addVar : Any".  Similarly with the other method I call.
When I right-click the "Model()" bit of code or one of the methods and select 'go to definition', I get a message saying 'no definition found for...'.
I also tried launching VSCode from the miniforge prompt with the SCIPopt environment activated, but that didn't help either.

We could found that model is belong to scip.pxd file.


But currently Pylance does not support Cython. So it's not a bug, it's just that this feature is not currently supported, and the same is true for .pyd files.
You could read these two issue on github for more details:
Pylance could support Cython
getting information from pyd files
If you want, you could create a feature request for comments and upvotes in github discussions.

Thank you! I'm glad to know that it wasn't a bug caused by me incorrectly setting up the project :).
